How to check for diagonal matches in a 3x5 2D string vector for a slot machine game?
Body:
I'm trying to implement logic for checking diagonal matches in a 3x5 2D string vector that looks like this:
[0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3][0,4]
[1,0][1,1][1,2][1,3][1,4]
[2,0][2,1][2,2][2,3][2,4]

Based on this matrix, the diagonals from top-left to bottom-right are:
[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]
[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]
[0,2], [1,3], [2,4]

I'm struggling to create the diagonal matching logic for my slot machine game. If there is a diagonal match, I want to add it to the total payout and then print the total payout. Once I get the forward direction, I think it will be easier to implement the reverse direction.
Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Function to print a 2D vector (for debugging purposes)
void print2D_Vector(const vector<vector<string>>& vec) {
    for (const auto& row : vec) {
        for (const auto& elem : row) {
            cout << elem << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<string>> reels = {
        {"cherry", "bell", "7", "bell", "diamond"},
        {"diamond", "cherry", "7", "bell", "$"},
        {"7", "diamond", "cherry", "$", "bell"}
    };

    print2D_Vector(reels);
    int total_Payout = 0;

    // Check for diagonal matches (top-left to bottom-right)
    for (int col = 0; col <= 2; ++col) {
        if (reels[0][col] == reels[1][col + 1] && reels[1][col + 1] == reels[2][col + 2]) {
            string match = reels[0][col];
            if (match == "cherry") {
                total_Payout += 5;
            } else if (match == "bell") {
                total_Payout += 10;
            }
        }
    }

    // Check for reverse diagonal matches (bottom-left to top-right)
    for (int col = 0; col <= 2; ++col) {
        if (reels[2][col] == reels[1][col + 1] && reels[1][col + 1] == reels[0][col + 2]) {
            string match = reels[2][col];
            if (match == "cherry") {
                total_Payout += 5;
            } else if (match == "bell") {
                total_Payout += 10;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Your payout is " + to_string(total_Payout) << endl;

    return 0;
}


I'm struggling to create the diagonal matching logic -- Before you write a single line of code, you should have the logic written down in discrete steps (your plan).  Once you determine that the logic works by going through it on paper, then you implement your logic in C++.  Trying to muddle through an already written program with bugs and/or logic that has not been worked out on paper is not a good idea.

@o.ayden76 And what is the problem with your code?

Based on this matrix, the diagonals from top-left to bottom-right are: -- If you know the matrix will always be 3x5, why do you even need a tricky for loop like that?  You know exactly what the 9 indices to check will be, so those indices can be simply hardcoded into an array or similar.  Then you loop over that array, put the items in maybe a std::set, and see if the size of the set is 1 (meaning all values found have matched).

Side note: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? - Don't do that.

Unrelated: you would do well to use an enum or other number as value in your slot machine and only use std::string when displaying to the user.

Your current code is messy because you are mixing up two concepts: picking lines from the slot machine and evaluating them.
Let us define the machinery for picking lines first:
using Pos = std::pair<int, int>;
using Line = std::vector<Pos>;
using Reels = std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>;

std::vector<std::string> evaluateLine(const Line& line, const Reels& reels) {
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    for (auto [row, col] : line) {
        ret.emplace_back(reels[row][col]);
    }
    return ret;
}

You are now in a position to loop over diagonals and calculate the final score:
const std::vector<Line> diagonals{
    // diagonals
    {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}},
    {{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}},
    {{0,2}, {1,3}, {2,4}},

    // anti-diagonals
    {{2,0}, {1,1}, {0,2}},
    {{2,1}, {1,2}, {0,3}},
    {{2,2}, {1,3}, {0,4}},
};

unsigned int finalScore(const Reels& reels) {
    unsigned int score = 0;
    for (const Line& line : diagonals) {
        auto icons = evaluateLine(line, reels);
        auto first = icons[0];
        if (std::any_of(begin(icons), end(icons),
            [&](const std::string& icon) { return icon != first; })) {
            continue;
        }

        if (first == "cherry") {
            score += 5;
        } else if (first == "bell")  {
            score += 10;
        }
    }
    return score;
}

